# Not able to set MPI nameserver?

Tags: mpi, intelhpc

Though, I found the `I_MPI_HYDRA_NAMESERVER` environment variable, but I could not succeed in using it. Do I need to start a server daemon?

```
char port_name[] = "exmplport",
    service_name[] = "exmplservice";
  if (world_p==0) 
 {
    MPI_Comm intercomm;
    MPI_Publish_name( service_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name );
    printf("Published Name\n");
    MPI_Unpublish_name( service_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name );
  } else
 {
    MPI_Lookup_name( service_name,MPI_INFO_NULL,port_name );
  }
```

Error:

```
[c210-008 c:3] export I_MPI_HYDRA_NAMESERVER=`hostname`:8000
[c210-008 c:4] make publishbug && mpiexec.hydra -n 2 publishbug
make: `publishbug' is up to date.
[mpiexec@c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu] HYD_sock_connect (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:228): Retrying connection, retry_count=1, retries=0
[mpiexec@c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu] HYD_sock_connect (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:243): unable to connect from "c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu" to "c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu" (Connection refused)
[mpiexec@c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu] mpiexec_connect_to_nameserver (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec_utils.c:425): unable to connect to nameserver
[mpiexec@c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu] mpiexec_publish_name (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec_utils.c:499): unable to connect to nameserver
[mpiexec@c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu] control_cb (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec.c:1484): error publishing service
[mpiexec@c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu] HYDI_dmx_poll_wait_for_event (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/demux/hydra_demux_poll.c:80): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@c210-008.frontera.tacc.utexas.edu] main (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec.c:2019): error waiting for event
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command ~$ hydra_nameserver to start hydra nameserver and then instead of directly giving port number I used MPI_Open_port() to get the port number and used it in MPI_Publish_name().

Later I tried

~$ make publishbug && I_MPI_HYDRA_NAMESERVER=`hostname` mpiexec.hydra -n 2 publishbug

I followed the below link to get a sample code (client.cpp & server.cpp)
https://github.com/SteffenSeckler/MPI_Connect_Test